# Erasing values from vector/map

Tags: c++, vector, dictionary, stl

Is this a safe way of deleting all entries from my vector or map

Vector

```
my_vector.erase(my_vector.begin(),my_vector.end());
```

For example for a map

```
my_map.erase(my_map.begin(),my_map.end());
```

The map or vector structure contains elements whose de-allocation is taken care in the destructor of those elements

Does the iterator value **returned by end()** become *invalid* as it starts to erase elements?

Comment: That is fine, but why not call `clear()`?

Comment: @juanchopanza curiosity thats all. Will use clear as it is more clean and clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both `erase()` methods are designed to work for iterator ranges excluding the second one.

```
// erase elements in range [a,b)
Iterator erase(Iterator a, Iterator b);
```

So it is safe to call `erase()` as you do, but you might as well call `clear()` in both cases.

Answer (score 1):

It's safe to call `erase(begin, end)` for `std::vector/std::map`, it also valid to other STL containers(`list, set, deque etc`) which provide `erase` member function and iterator to iterate through elements.

As long as you pass in valid range(beg,end), below two ranges are also valid, `erase` takes no efforts:

```
c.erase(c.begin(), c.begin());
c.erase(c.end(), clend());
```

---

`std::vector::erase(beg,end)` Removes all elements of the range [beg,end) and returns the
position of the next element.

`std::map::erase(beg,end)` Removes all elements of the range [beg,end) and returns
the following position (returned nothing before C++11).

---

In STL internal implementation, it calls `erase(begin,end)` in a few functions like:

```
void clear() noexcept;
Effects: Behaves as if the function calls:
          erase(begin(), end());

void assign(size_type n, const T& t);
Effects:
   erase(begin(), end());
   insert(begin(), first, last);
```

As you can see, `erase(begin(),end());` is the same as `clear()`.

Alternatively, you could call `swap` to clear a STL container which is suggested in `More Effective STL`:

```
vector<Contestant> v;
vector<Contestant>().swap(v); //clear v and minimize its capacity
```